# pandas select conditionally specific columns in dataframe with another condition results in concatenation

Tags: python, pandas

I want to select specific columns by their name using loc, since i want to do it with another condition.
I get weird behavior trying to achieve this using

```
df.loc[,conditionOne | conditionTwo]
```

one of the conditions is whether a column name is in a specific list of names, and the second condition is another condtion (here is the median of the column):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [0,0,0,0], 'B' : [1,2,3, 5],  'C' : [10,20,30, 50]})
df.columns.values
keepColumnsNames = ['A', 'c']
condtionOne = df.mean()>2
print(condtionOne)
"#A    False"
"#B     True"
"#C     True"
"#dtype: bool" 
condtionTwo=pd.DataFrame(df.columns.values).iloc[:,0].isin(keepColumnsNames)
print(condtionTwo)
"#A    False"
"#B     True"
"#C     True"
```

Now when i want to do an or operator between the two conditions i get the next weird behavior:

```
print(condtionOne | condtionTwo )
"#0    False"
"#1    False"
"#2    False"
"#A    False"
"#B     True"
"#C     True"
"#dtype: bool"
```

while I would expect to get

```
"#False"
"#True"
"#True"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need same indices in both masks:

```
condtionTwo=pd.DataFrame(df.columns.values,index=df.columns).iloc[:,0].isin(keepColumnsNames)
print(condtionTwo)
A     True
B    False
C    False
Name: 0, dtype: bool
```

Or better, thanks @Julien Marrec for comment is create array with no indices:

```
condtionTwo = df.columns.isin(keepColumnsNames) 
print(condtionTwo)
[ True False False]

print(condtionOne | condtionTwo)
A    True
B    True
C    True
dtype: bool
```

All together:

```
df1 = df.loc[:, condtionOne | condtionTwo]
print (df1)
   A  B   C
0  0  1  10
1  0  2  20
2  0  3  30
3  0  5  50
```

What is same as:

```
df1 = df.loc[:, (df.mean() > 2) | (df.columns.isin(keepColumnsNames))]
print (df1)
   A  B   C
0  0  1  10
1  0  2  20
2  0  3  30
3  0  5  50
```

Comment: df.columns.isin(keepColumnsNames) is sufficient here

Answer (score 0):

This should do it in fewer characters:

```
condtionOne = df.mean()>2
condtionTwo = ['A', 'C']
df.loc[:, (conditionOne).values|(df.columns.isin(condition2))]
```